# Getting type of an object

Tags: c++, typeinfo

I'm trying to do something along these lines:

```
int var = 5;
std::numeric_limits<typeid(var)>::max();
```

but surprise, surprise it doesn't work. How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the type:

```
int the_max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

You can use a helper function template:

```
template <typename T>
T type_max(T)
{
    return std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
}

// use:
int x = 0;
int the_max = type_max(x);
```

In C++0x you can use `decltype`:

```
int x = 0;
int the_max = std::numeric_limits<decltype(x)>::max();
```

Answer (score 4):

`typeid` does not return a type, but a runtime `type_info` object. That template parameter expects a compile-time type, so it won't work.

In some compilers like gcc, you could use

```
std::numeric_limits<typeof(var)>::max();
```

Otherwise, you could try [Boost.Typeof](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/typeof.html).

In C++0x, you could use

```
std::numeric_limits<decltype(var)>::max();
```

(BTW, [@James's `type_max`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596349/getting-type-of-an-object/3596361#3596361) is much better if you don't need the type explicitly.)